# Where I can find the complete Psalms?

Tags: psalms

Where I can find the complete Psalms of David? The bible is a compilation of many books in one Book, I want to find the Psalms of David.

Comment: Roughly in the middle?

Comment: @NigelJ if you want Psalm 151 you'll have to look in an Eastern Orthodox Bible though.

Comment: In the Old Testament (Hebrew scriptures) the book called Psalms is included. King David was not the only author of those Psalms. Some of them are ascribed to collections of Asaph, or the sons of Korah, King David, and perhaps other kings in the Davidic line. Moses is also author of some of them. 34 of the Psalms lack any superscription and are called 'orphan psalms' because the author is not known.

Comment: In my "main" copy of the Bible (the NIV Study Bible by Zondervan), each of the Psalms is headed with a note indicating the authorship -- of David, of Asaph, of the sons of Korah, and so on.  I'm sure that many other versions and translations provide that as well.  That would let you filter through and specifically find the ones authored by David.  Offhand I don't know of any other ancient sources for David's psalms outside the ones compiled into the biblical book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [Bible Hub](https://biblehub.com/psalms/) or in any physical copy of the Bible, "roughly in the middle" (thanks @curiousdannii).

David is *specifically denoted* the author of 75 of the 150 Psalms, which are listed [here, on GotQuestions](https://www.gotquestions.org/Psalms-David.html). The others have no mention or limited background information so we are uncertain, and others are written by other people. 73 are listed specifically in Psalms as being a psalm of David, and 2 (Psalm 2 and 95) are mentioned in the New Testament as being written by David (see Acts 4:25, Hebrews 4:7). Because of this, it seems reasonable to conclude that David wrote some-many of the other "anonymous" Psalms, but just that his name isn't listed.

As for as other authors of the psalms in the Book of Psalms, [here is a short discussion](https://www.gotquestions.org/Psalms-authors.html). Other authors include:

- Asaph (and family) (12 psalms): 50; 73—83
- The sons of Korah (11 psalms): 42; 44—49; 84—85; 87—88
- Heman (1 psalm, with the sons of Korah): 88
- Solomon (2 psalms): 72 and 127
- Moses (1 psalm): 90
- Ethan the Ezrahite (1 psalm): 89

And comment by @MattGutting said that Psalm 151 is in the Orthodox Bible, as apparently that isn't in other Bibles. I don't know anything about that.